# Find focus, directrix, and graph of a parabola

Tags: conic-sections

> Find vertex focus and directrix of parabola $$9x^2+16y^2-24xy-18x-101y+109=0.$$ Then sketch the graph.

**My work**. $3 x -4 Y^2 =18 x + 101 y - 109$. Here $Y=3x-4y$ and $X=18 x + 101 y - 109$ then I cannot understand what to do.

Comment: Please, show what you have attempted.

Comment: 3 x minus 4 Y to the power 2 equal to 18 x + 101 y - 109 here capital Y is equal to 3 x minus 4 Y and capital x is equal to 18 x + 101 y - 109 then I cannot understand what to do

Comment: Please see answer at www.wolframalpha.com.

Answer (score 1):

After taking a rotation of $\alpha=\arctan(3/4)$ around the origin, that is 
$$x=\frac{4u-3v}{5}\quad y=\frac{3u+4v}{5},$$
the parabola becomes
$$25v^2-70v-75u+109=0,$$
or
$$Y=(u-4/5)=\frac{(v-7/5)^2}{3}=\frac{1}{3}X^2.$$
Now recall that for [parabola](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parabola#Parabola_as_graph_of_a_function) of the form $Y=AX^2$, the focus is the point $(0,\frac{1}{4A})$ and the directrix is the line $Y=-\frac{1}{4A}$.
Hence, going back with the substitutions, we obtain that the focus is
$$(X,Y)=\left(0,\frac{1}{4(1/3)}\right)\rightarrow
(v,u)=\left(\frac{7}{5},\frac{1}{4(1/3)}+\frac{4}{5}\right)\rightarrow (x,y)=\left(\frac{2}{5},\frac{41}{20}\right).$$
Are you able to find the directrix?

Comment: @user476543 Any further doubt? BTW if you are new here take a few seconds for a tour https://math.stackexchange.com/tour